# Как подставить переменную в URL при отправке через ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Я получаю параметр Click ID таким способом:

```
<span id="cl_id" class="password-span" style="visibility: hidden"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["clickid"]);?></span>
```

Как мне подставить полученный Click ID сюда (вместо *CLICK ID*)?:

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', `http://Ваш_сервер/*CLICK ID*`);
xhr.onload = function() {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
};
xhr.send();
```

Comment: cl_id.innerHTML?

Comment: @nklagas Ответ выше полностью решит Ваши проблемы. Добавьте его в `js`. Например `var clickID = cl_id.innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

Очень просто:

```
HTML 
вместо:

<span id="cl_id" class="password-span" style="visibility: hidden">
   <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["clickid"]);?>
</span>
это:
<script>
   var cl_id = `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["clickid"]);?>}`;
</script>


JS:
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', `http://Ваш_сервер/${cl_id}`);
xhr.onload = function() {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
};
xhr.send();
```

Должно помочь

Answer (score 0):

если сам скрипт ajax находится в отдельном файле то нужно зарание определить переменную

```
<script>
var clId = '<?=htmlspecialchars($_GET["clickid"])?>'
</script>
```

или

```
<script>
var clId = '<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["clickid"]); ?>'
</script>
```

затем подставить в запрос

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://Ваш_сервер/' + clId);
xhr.onload = function() {
   console.log(xhr.responseText);
};
xhr.send();
```

но если скрипт находится прямо в файле *php*

то можно так

```
<script>
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', `http://Ваш_сервер/<?=htmlspecialchars($_GET["clickid"])?>`);
    xhr.onload = function() {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    };
    xhr.send();

</script>
```